# Outlook weblink does not always correctly open the mail

Tags: outlook-restapi

When I'm getting the property weblink from a message through the outlook API 2.0 REST call, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

That's to say:
For my testaccount dirk@useitgroup.onmicrosoft.com.
When I get the weblink I get something like:
https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AQMkAGI...%3D%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem.
opening this weblink correctly opens the mail after redirecting to something like.
https://outlook.office365.com/mail/deeplink?ItemID=AQMkAGI...%3D%3D&exvsurl=1.

for my live.com account I also get a weblink
for instance something like:
https://outlook.live.com/owa/?ItemID=AQMkA...3D%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem.
which then after redirection gets translated to something like.
https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/deeplink?ItemID=AQMkA...%3d%3d.

This link never opens the mail, but keeps showing me "loading" instead.

The difference seems to be the outlook.office365.com vs the outlook.live.com.
My live account is for a family office365 subscription.
Is there any way to get this to work with a live account as well?

Comment: Same link format is used from Microsoft To Do when you click 'Open in Outlook'. Doesn't work for me either.