# Message webLink not working for outlook.com accounts

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-app

I’m working on an add-in for Microsoft Outlook, and we need to provide our users with direct links to specific emails.  We’ve been using the webLink property of the message object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0

At some point recently, it appears that these web links have stopped working for outlook.com users.  Instead of opening up to the email, the page will either appear to load forever or show a page saying “Get Outlook on your phone for free” with a form to submit a phone number to receive an Outlook mobile app download link via text.  These web links still work for all the Office 365 accounts we have tested.

Whether we fetch a message and its web link using the REST API V2 or the Graph API, we get the same web link that will not work for outlook.com accounts.

It looks like we’ve been seeing the same behavior described in this question: [Outlook weblink does not always correctly open the mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613815/outlook-weblink-does-not-always-correctly-open-the-mail)

Is this a known issue, and if so are there any known workarounds?  Thank you.

Comment: Similar issue [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1095)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the same issue on GitHub: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1095

The fix for that is being worked on.

Comment: Thanks! Yes this looks like it is the same issue.